# Hibernate mapping SQL View

Tags: hibernate, view, hql

```
2012-06-13 18:09:47,777 ERROR [main] SchemaUpdate - Unsuccessful: 
alter table *************.******** add index FKBCA22C66AF04751F(xxxxxxx, zzzzzz),
add constraint FKBCA22C66AF04751F foreign key (xxxxxxxx, zzzzzzz) references
***********.************* (categoria_id, azienda_id)

2012-06-13 18:09:47,779 ERROR [main] SchemaUpdate - '************.********' 
is not BASE TABLE
```

I've a view in my schema, but I don't understand correctly how mapping it with hibernate on my project

Answer (score 0):

Based to the log it seems to be the case that you try to update definition of database view via [SchemaUpdate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaUpdate.html). Most likely that is not what you want to do.

How to avoid that depends about how you configured Hibernate. If it is via hibernate.cfg.xml, 
you should remove following (or change update to validate):

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```